# Combine Excel Files Mac

Tags: automator

I wish to combine several Excel Workbooks into one workbook.
I wish to use an Automator Application to do so.
I tried creating one using the Automator wizard but it does not work.
I am using latest Mac OS
RDB Merge addon is not working.
thank you.

Comment: try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: thank you. i just managed to do it . Ben Waldies podcast videos on Automator helped.All i needed to do was drag and drop the files on the newly ceated script icon :)